# Getting error while importing {ref} from vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a newbie to vue js learning from vue-mastery tutorials and I wrote a code by seeing the tutorial
My code is

```
<template>
<div>Capacity: {{ capacity }}</div>
</template>

<script type="module">
import { ref } from "vue";
export default{
setup(){
const capacity = ref(3);
return { capacity };
}
};
</script>
```

I am getting the error in terminal when I run this code is
**"export 'ref' was not found in 'vue'**
And in web browser error is
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "capacity" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

--->  at src/App.vue

My requirement is to print capacity: 3 in the browser anyone please help me Thanks in advance!

Comment: `setup()` is part of the Composition API, which is a valid structure only in Vue 3.0+ or with the `vuejs/composition-api` plugin. Are you using one of those?

Comment: Yes @AugustoMoura My vue --version is @vue/cli 4.2.2

Comment: @AugustoMoura When I did this command  npm list vue
I got this  vue@2.6.11 
can you please help me??

Comment: vue-cli is not vue it's a cli tool, so using v-4.2.2 reallt only affects how you bootstrap your project.

Comment: yes mine vue is version 2

Comment: @Michael and this is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sky-bg65m in which I had replicated the error which I got please once see and help me out

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using the [Composition API](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com), which is not supported in the current version of Vue (it will be part of Vue 3, released later this year)

For now, you can either [download the Composition API plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/master/README.md), or switch to the [Options API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), which is the current supported way of making single file components in Vue

Comment: Yes I downloaded used it the error in terminal gone but this error coming in webpage 

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "capacity" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>

Comment: Please help me @Jason

Comment: Are you importing `ref` from `vue` or `@vue/composition-api`? It works for me @stack

Comment: The options API might be a better starting point for learning Vue, as it is simpler and will keep working even in Vue 3 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

Vue2 JS doesn't support {ref} package.

There are 2 methods

1. import @vue/composition-api npm package and you can use like this

   ```
    import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api"
    export default{
      setup() {
        const capacity = ref(3);
        return { capacity }
      }
   }
   ```

2. You can use the traditional method

   ```
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         capacity: 3
       }
     }
   }
   ```